# How do I make a crawler extracting information from relative paths?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am trying to make a simple crawler that extracts links from the "See About" section from this link https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_scraping. That is 19 links in total, which I have managed to extract using Beautiful Soup. However I get them as relative links in a list, which I also need to fix by making them into absolute links. Intended result would look like this: [image]

Then I wanted to use those same 19 links and extract further information from them. For example the first paragraph from each of the 19 links. So far I have this:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.parse import urljoin
from urllib.request import urlopen

url = 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_scraping'
data = requests.get('https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_scraping').text

soup = BeautifulSoup(data, 'html.parser')

links = soup.find('div', {'class':'div-col'})
test = links.find_all('a', href=True)

data = []
for link in links.find_all('a'):
    data.append(link.get('href'))
#print(data)

soupNew = BeautifulSoup(''.join(data), 'html.parser')
print(soupNew.find_all('p')[0].text)

#test if there is any <p> tag, which returns empty, so I have not looped correctly.
x = soupNew.findAll('p')
if x is not None and len(x) > 0:
    section = x[0]
print(x)
```

My main issue is that I simply cant find a way to loop through the 19 links and look for the information I need. I am trying to learn Beautiful Soup and Python so I would prefer to stick with those for now even though there might be better options for doing this out there. So I just need some help or preferably an simple example to explain the process of doing said things above. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should split your code like you split your problems.

1. Your first problem was to get a list, so you could write a method called get_urls

   ```
    def get_urls():
        url = 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_scraping'
        data = requests.get(url).text
        soup = BeautifulSoup(data, 'html.parser')
        links = soup.find('div', {'class':'div-col'})
        data = []
        for link in links.find_all('a'):
            data.append("https://en.wikipedia.org"+link.get('href'))
        return data
   ```
2. You wanted to get the first paragraph of every url. With little research i just got this one

   ```
    def get_first_paragraph(url):
        data = requests.get(url).text
        soup = BeautifulSoup(data, 'html.parser')
        return soup.p.text
   ```
3. now all has to be wired up

   ```
    def iterate_through_urls(urls):
        for url in urls:
            print(get_first_paragraph(url))


    def run():
        urls = get_urls()
        iterate_through_urls(urls)
   ```